# jsonp with ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I have this code:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: URL,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    jsonpCallback: callback,
    success: function (data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
        alert("success");
    }, 
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    }

});
```

the the status response is 200 but it's treated as an error.
I can see this on chrome response tab:

```js
{
  "error": "cannot create user because user already exists",
  "code": 404
}
```

<-- this is the data returned by the server

and I can't get that data using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it to work with this code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URL,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "text/javascript",
        success: function (data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
             alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }, 
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
             alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        },
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
             alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        }

    });
```

hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I have one question. How does you URL looks like? How do you create your JSONP object?

Comment: URL is on a private server and I was "querying" from my local machine.  
Here are good resources:

http://vaboone.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/jsonp-with-node-js-express/ and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928391/using-jsonp-in-express-js-for-node-js